# Getting Exact Pattern Match with grep and sed

Tags: string, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm solving a bunch of text strings using `grep` and `sed` in which I only want the **`stdout`** to print the data after **`package:`** and ends at the folder name without the ending **`/`**.

For example:

```
data/dataapp/com.android.chrome-DeX_54==
System/app/Keychain
vendor/app/NlpService
```

This is the sample...

```
package:data/app/com.android.chrome-DeX_54==/base.apk=com.android.chrome
package:data/dataapp/ExactCalculator/ExactCalculator.apk=com.android.calculator2
package:data/hw_init/cust/app/Email/Email.apk=com.android.email
package:system/app/KeyChain/KeyChain.apk=com.android.keychain
package:system/delapp/WallpaperBackup/WallpaperBackup.apk=com.android.wallpaperbackup
package:system/framework/framework-res.apk=android
package:system/priv-app/CIT/CIT.apk=com.ontim.cit
package:vendor/app/NlpService/NlpService.apk=com.mediatek.nlpservice
```

I'm not getting the exact output I want so any help would be appreciated.

P.S: *I'm learning `grep` and `sed` just for fun.*

Comment: Check out grep's `-o` flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
grep -Po '(?<=package:).+(?=/[^/]*$)' input.txt
```

Results:

```
data/app/com.android.chrome-DeX_54==
data/dataapp/ExactCalculator
data/hw_init/cust/app/Email
system/app/KeyChain
system/delapp/WallpaperBackup
system/framework
system/priv-app/CIT
vendor/app/NlpService
```

- The `-P` option enables a Perl compatible regex.
- The `-o` option tells `grep` to print only the matched substring(s).
- The pattern `(?<=package:)` is a `positive lookbehind assertion` and
  the matched substring is not included in the output of `grep -o`.
- The pattern `(?=/[^/]*$)` is a `positive lookahead assertion` as well.

The `sed` alternative will be:

```
sed 's#\(^package:\)\(.\+\)\(/[^/]*$\)#\2#' input.txt
```

or

```
sed -E 's#(^package:)(.+)(/[^/]*$)#\2#' input.txt
```

The latter will be more legible.

You'll see the `positive lookarounds` can be substituted with the back reference of `sed` just by discarding the unnecessary groups.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks **@tshiono**, it worked perfectly although the pattern is so much complicated for me. Can u do it with `SED` also? And by the way what's the best source to learn `GREP` and `SED`. I've looked on `Youtube` but haven't find a full Course on them.

Comment: @Mujtaba Good to know it works. I've updated my answer by adding a `sed` alternative. (I suppose @potong's -n option solution will be more smart. I just directly translated my `grep` version to `sed`.)

Comment: Regarding the regex, although both `grep` and `sed` support regex, they are different tools for different purposes. I'd recommend `sed` or `awk` to start with. Then if you need powerful regex next, please try `perl`, `ruby` or `python`.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's#^package:\(.*\)/.*#\1#p' file
```

As this may be a filtering operation use the `-n` option to explicitly print results. The regexp starts with `^` in the substitution command which anchors `package:` to the start of the line and the uses `.*` to greedily consume the remainder of the line. However, the next character it tries to match is a `/` and so the regexp engine backtracks to find it and then the following `.*` again swallows the remainder of the line. The quoted parens `\(...\)` capture this part of the regexp and it is represented in the  RHS of the substitute command by `\1` known as a back reference. The `p` flag at the end of the substitute command explicitly prints the amended line in its current state.

N.B. That with the substitute command, the programmer can choose its delimiter. In documentation the command will usually be written `s/LHS/RHS/flags` where the delimiter is `/` but can be any character as in the above solution `#` was chosen to reduce the need for quoting the `/` character, LHS = regexp on the left hand side, RHS = replacement and flags = additional operations  such as `g` meaning substitute globally throughout the line/file and `p` meaning print the line in its current state following a successful substitution (there are others see sed documentation.

Comment: Thanks **@potong** for this great explanation.